# Branch.io How long are deferred deep links stored on Server?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

My team is testing Branch.io deferred deep linking and it seems like if the user clicked on the link and installed application after some time (~12 hours) deferred deep link didn't work.

We have logged only this information:

```
[AnyHashable("+clicked_branch_link"): 0, AnyHashable("+is_first_session"): 1]
```

but the right link haven't handled at all. How long are deferred deep links stored on Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duration of the deep linking is by default set for 120 minutes. If a user downloads your app from a Branch Link but opens it post 120 minutes, they'd not deep link inside the application.

This parameter is called `DeepLinking Duration`. You can configure the default value set by going to `Attribution Windows` inside the Configuration section of your Branch Dashboard.

The minimum value is 0 and the maximum value is 10080 minutes(7 days).

Comment: @Katrik are you sure about maximum value? Because we set in POST call 7889238 (3 months) and we have received 200 OK.

Comment: duration | Optional

In seconds. Only set this key if you want to override the match duration for deep link matching. This is the time that Branch allows a click to remain outstanding and be eligible to be matched with a new app session. This is default set to 7200 (2 hours) ---

There is no maximum value stated here.